# How to get the language specific messages using google closure template

Tags: closures, google-closure, google-closure-library, google-closure-templates

Am trying to implement internationalization support to my project for this people    suggested  google Closure Templates.but am very new to closure templates.am trying to get the language specific messages  using closure template but am not getting in xlf file.If any one knows how to generate language specific messages using closure template, please tell me the steps.that's great help to me.

My .soy file code as bellow.

```
{namespace poc} 
/** 
*Testing message translation 
*@param pageTitle 
*/ 
{template .translate} 
<HTML> 
<Head> 
<title>{$pageTitle} 
</title> 
</head> 
<div> 
{msg desc="Hello"}Hello{/msg} 
</div> 
</html> 
{/template} 

and generated .xlf content as bellow 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <file original="SoyMsgBundle" datatype="x-soy-msg-bundle" xml:space="preserve" source-language="en" target-language="pt-BR">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="2286494898080570401" datatype="html">
        <source>Thanks</source>
        <target/>
        <note priority="1" from="description">Says thanks</note>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you already used the SoyMsgExtractor to create the base xlf. Next you need to make translations of this base xlf to the languages you want to support. A file for each language is created. I used the xliff exitor from Translution. http://sourceforge.net/projects/eviltrans.

Next, using the SoyToJsSrcCompiler a translation soy can be made per language:

java -jar SoyToJsSrcCompiler.jar --shouldGenerateGoogMsgDefs --bidiGlobalDir 1 --messageFilePathFormat Filename_en-us.xliff --outputPathFormat FileName_fr.js *.soy

This will create a Filename._fr.js file that contains the compiled soy file.

Including this file instead of the original soy (or compiled) will create a localized version.

Good luck!

\Rene

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest way is to make (i.e. generate from whatever source) a separate js file which contains one messages object and reference it through an extern declared function.

it justs works and has no complicated dependencies.